# How to Show/Hide multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know that this question has been asked many times before, but I can't find a solution excepting of hard-coding the jQuery file...
So, I have to show a description when user presses a button and there are multiple descriptions, each with their buttons.

This is what I've done so far...

HTML:

```
<div id="trDest1" class="trDest">
    <!-- Some content here -->
    <button class="expandArrow">Show</button>
    <button class="closeArrow">Hide</button>
</div>
<div id="trDest1_details" class="details">
    <p>show details</p>
</div>

<div id="trDest2" class="trDest">
    <!-- Some content here -->
    <button class="expandArrow">Show</button>
    <button class="closeArrow">Hide</button>
</div>
<div id="trDest2_details" class="details">
    <p>show details</p>
</div>

<div id="trDest3" class="trDest">
    <!-- Some content here -->
    <button class="expandArrow">Show</button>
    <button class="closeArrow">Hide</button>
</div>
<div id="trDest3_details" class="details">
    <p>show details</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.closeArrow {
  display: none;
}

.visible-description .expandArrow {
  display: none;
}

.visible-description .closeArrow {
  display: inline;
}

.visible-description + .trip_details {
  display: block;
}

.details {
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
  // Show/hide Descriptions
  $('#trDest1 .expandArrow').click(function(){
    $('#trDest1').addClass('visible-description');
    $('#trDest1_details').show();
  });

  $('#trDest1 .closeArrow').click(function(){
    $('#trDest1').removeClass('visible-description');
    $('#trDest1_details').hide();
  });

  // Show/hide Descriptions
  $('#trDest2 .expandArrow').click(function(){
    $('#trDest2').addClass('visible-description');
    $('#trDest2_details').show();
  });

  $('#trDest2 .closeArrow').click(function(){
    $('#trDest2').removeClass('visible-description');
    $('#trDest2_details').hide();
  });

  // Show/hide Descriptions
  $('#trDest3 .expandArrow').click(function(){
    $('#trDest3').addClass('visible-description');
    $('#trDest3_details').show();
  });

  $('#trDest3 .closeArrow').click(function(){
    $('#trDest3').removeClass('visible-description');
    $('#trDest3_details').hide();
  });
```

As you can see, I wrote a function for each of those `divs` and I'm wondering if there is another way to clean these functions and add only a function which can do the same...

I can't change the structure of the HTML code.

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/q84Lnw0y/

Comment: If you know how many divs there are, you could try with a for loop...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use following snippet to target relevant elements:

```
$('.expandArrow, .hideArrow').on('click', function(){
    var isExpand = $(this).hasClass('expandArrow');
    $(this).closest('.trDest').toggleClass('visible-description', isExpand).next().toggle(isExpand);
});
```

### -jsFiddle

**Description:**

```
$(this).closest('.trDest') // Get closest ancestor with class trDest
    .toggleClass('visible-description', isExpand) // Add class `visible-description` if second param `isExpand` is true, else remove class
    .next() // Get immediate next sibling element
    .toggle(isExpand); // Show if `isExpand` is true, else hide it
```

Comment: Small improvement, cache the result of `$(this).hasClass('expandArrow')`

Comment: @Tushar Ya, i was thinking about it. Let me cache it :)

Comment: And it can be done in one line, but less readable `$('.expandArrow, .hideArrow').on('click', function () {
    var hasClass = $(this).hasClass('expandArrow');
    $(this).closest('.trDest').toggleClass('visible-description', hasClass).next().toggle(hasClass);
});`

Comment: Thank you @A.Wolff , this works perfectly! As an improvement, is there any function that scrolls to the visible details when the user clicks the expand arrow?

Comment: @PavelValeriu Ya, there are some ways, the native js one is `scrollIntoView`: `$(this).closest('.trDest').toggleClass('visible-description', isExpand).next().toggle(isExpand)[0].scrollIntoView();`

Comment: @Tushar Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome! I guess `scrollIntoView` is not supported by all browsers(?). Also, hash can be used

Comment: @Tushar AFAIK, there is some bug in IE but regarding child of scrollable container, still AFAIK, works to set non scrollable element into view. A jQuery animate() could be better for sure. But then, i'd go with Thomas answer, using some kind of animation to display elements

Comment: Great, scrollIntoView is working just fine, maybe I'll try to add some jQuery animation for this :). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally suggest the following:

```
// delegating the .trDest elements to detect the 'click' events on
// the descendent elements ('.expandArrow, .hideArrow'):
$('.trDest').on('click', '.expandArrow, .hideArrow', function (e) {

    // a reference to the clicked element:
    var arrow = $(this),

        // a reference to the element you want to affect:
        nextDetails = arrow.closest('div').next('.details');

    // checking that the clicked button has the class of
    // 'expandArrow':
    if (arrow.is('.expandArrow')) {

        // it is, we find all the '.details' elements,
        // that are not the the element to affect,
        // and slide them up (hide() could be used,
        // but slideUp() is often less visually jarring):
        $('.details').not(nextDetails).slideUp();

        // then we slideDown() the element we wish to show
        // (if it's already visible then nothing happens):
        nextDetails.slideDown();

    // otherwise the element (because of the restrictions
    // in the selector for the on() method) must be
    // .hideArrow, in which case we hide the
    // nextDetails element by sliding it up:
    } else {
        nextDetails.slideUp();
    }

// here we now look for the descendant '.hideArrow'
// elements and trigger the click event in order that
// that the 'nextDetails' elements are hidden on page-load:
}).find('.hideArrow').click();
```

```js
$('.trDest').on('click', '.expandArrow, .hideArrow', function(e) {
  var arrow = $(this),
    nextDetails = arrow.closest('div').next('.details');

  if (arrow.is('.expandArrow')) {
    $('.details').not(nextDetails).slideUp();
    nextDetails.slideDown();
  } else {
    nextDetails.slideUp();
  }
}).find('.hideArrow').click();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="trDest1" class="trDest">
  <!-- Some content here -->
  <button class="expandArrow">Show</button>
  <button class="hideArrow">Hide</button>
</div>
<div id="trDest2_details" class="details">
  <p>show details</p>
</div>
<div id="trDest2" class="trDest">
  <!-- Some content here -->
  <button class="expandArrow">Show</button>
  <button class="hideArrow">Hide</button>
</div>
<div id="trDest2_details" class="details">
  <p>show details</p>
</div>
<div id="trDest3" class="trDest">
  <!-- Some content here -->
  <button class="expandArrow">Show</button>
  <button class="hideArrow">Hide</button>
</div>
<div id="trDest2_details" class="details">
  <p>show details</p>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ovpftvtk/).

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).
- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/).
- [`slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/).

Comment: Nice one but better would be to define visibility by default, not trigger click event: https://jsfiddle.net/ovpftvtk/1/  (I'm sure you know...)  But still, not same behaviour as OP's code, only one `.details` is shown at a time (even i know you know what you are doing...) :)

Comment: @A.Wolff: thank you very much; I do that because I'm a hobbyist and I remember how difficult it is to learn how JavaScript (or its libraries) worked, and how much I appreciated the time some users spent explaining code to me. Given that, it seems only fair that I try to help teach as much as possible (within the constraints of the the code, obviously).

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want

```
$('.trDest button').on('click', function() {
    var myButton = $(this),
        trDest = myButton.parent(),
        detailsId = $('#' + trDest.attr('id') + '_details');

    trDest.toggleClass('visible-description');
    myButton.hasClass('expandArrow') ? detailsId.show() : detailsId.hide();
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/orysrvb2/1/

Comment: Switched addClass() to  toggleClass() to make it work as intended. Also, this is a drop-in replacement for the javascript in OP description. No CSS or html changes needed

Answer (score 0):

one of the ways:

```
var numberDiv = 3;
for(var i=0; i < 4; i++){
  $('#trDest' + i + ' .expandArrow').i = i;
  $('#trDest' + i + ' .closeArrow').i = i;

  $('#trDest' + i + ' .expandArrow').click(function(){
    $('#trDest'+this.i).addClass('visible-description');
    $('#trDest'+this.i+' _details').show();
  });

  $('#trDest' + i + ' .closeArrow').click(function(){
    $('#trDest' + this.i).removeClass('visible-description');
    $('#trDest'+ this.i +' _details').hide();
  });
}
```

See if this helps

Comment: Still e.g: `'#trDest' + i + '.expandArrow'` should be: `'#trDest' + i + ' .expandArrow'`  Otherwise, you have fixed closure issue :)

Comment: Can't you use an IIFE instead of setting `i` on the buttons? `(function(i){ //Code })(i);`

Comment: @Arg0n Sure you can and it is usually how it is done (or using function passing param)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change your HTML, maybe something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/k2wnyfha/1/) will work:

JavaScript

```
$('.expandArrow').click(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    parent.addClass('visible-description');
    parent.next('.details').show();
    parent.find(".hideArrow").show();
});

$('.hideArrow').click(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    parent.removeClass('visible-description');
    parent.next('.details').hide();
    parent.find(".hideArrow").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q84Lnw0y/2/)

```js
  // Show/hide Descriptions
  $('.trDest .expandArrow').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next().removeClass('hidden');
  });

  $('.trDest .hideArrow').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next().addClass('hidden');
  });
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="trDest1" class="trDest">
  <!-- Some content here -->
  <button class="expandArrow">Show</button>
  <button class="hideArrow">Hide</button>
</div>
<div id="trDest2_details" class="details">
  <p>show details</p>
</div>

<div id="trDest2" class="trDest">
  <!-- Some content here -->
  <button class="expandArrow">Show</button>
  <button class="hideArrow">Hide</button>
</div>
<div id="trDest2_details" class="details">
  <p>show details</p>
</div>

<div id="trDest3" class="trDest">
  <!-- Some content here -->
  <button class="expandArrow">Show</button>
  <button class="hideArrow">Hide</button>
</div>
<div id="trDest2_details" class="details">
  <p>show details</p>
</div>
```